# Swift Appending to array From inside Loop

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, alamofire, swifty-json

## Needed

What I want to do, is loop through these json results; for each of the categories create a header in the UITableView and for each of the posts under the categories create a tableview cell

## Project Files

https://jumpshare.com/v/Otai3BBXYwfvyz8jb53k

## Problem

For some reason when I try to append to an array, form inside a for loop it is not adding.

Here is my code:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success:
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)
                
                for (_, subJson) in json {
                    for (index, data) in subJson {
                        for (title, objects) in data {
                            sectionsArray.append(Sections(title: title, objects: objects.self.arrayValue.map { $0.string!}))
                            
                            
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

When I add in some prints (under: sectionsArray.append) to test if there is data:

```
print("--")

print(title)

print(objects.self.arrayValue.map { $0.string!})

print(Sections(title: title, objects: objects.self.arrayValue.map { $0.string!}))
```

I get this result in the console:

> --
>
> Category1
>
> ["Post1cat1"]
>
> Sections(headings: "Category1", items: ["Post1cat1"])
>
> --
>
> Category2
>
> ["Post1cat2", "Post2cat2"]
>
> Sections(headings: "Category2", items: ["Post1cat2", "Post2cat2"])

However, When I run the app - in the tableview all that is displayed is the items from the animals array.

[image]

## Full View Controller

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class SectionsData {

let url = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/3nuvn";

var myArray: [String] = []


func getSectionsFromData() -> [Sections] {

    var sectionsArray = [Sections]()
    
    let animals = Sections(title: "Animals", objects: ["Cats", "Dogs", "Birds", "Lions"])
  
    
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success:
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let json = JSON(value)
                
                for (_, subJson) in json {
                    for (_, data) in subJson {
                        for (title, objects) in data {
                            sectionsArray.append(Sections(title: title, objects: objects.self.arrayValue.map { $0.string!}))
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    sectionsArray.append(animals);
   
    
    return sectionsArray
}
}
```

Comment: Your `Alamofire` request is performed asynchronous.

Comment: ok, but that doesnt answer the question. How do I fix it ?

Comment: After you add the data to your array, call `reloadData()` on your table view.

Comment: Since the `Alamofire ` request is asynchronously, you should include a completion block in the function

Comment: @Breek - I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: @MrBeardsley - Is that correct? The data is loaded further down and returned. There is no direct passing to the table form that for loop.

Comment: I have added the Projects Files in an edit of the post

Answer (score 1):

The code with completion block should like this:

```
func getSectionsFromData(completion: ([Sections]? -> Void)){

        var sectionsArray = [Sections]()

        let animals = Sections(title: "Animals", objects: ["Cats", "Dogs", "Birds", "Lions"])

        Alamofire.request(.GET, url).validate().responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                if let value = response.result.value {
                    let json = JSON(value)

                    for (_, subJson) in json {
                        for (_, data) in subJson {
                            for (title, objects) in data {
                                sectionsArray.append(Sections(title: title, objects: objects.self.arrayValue.map { $0.string!}))
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
                sectionsArray.append(animals)
                completion(sectionsArry)
            case .Failure(let error):
                print(error)
                sectionsArray.append(animals)
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

When you call the func:

```
var sections: [Sections] = []
SectionsData().getSectionsFromData({ sectionsArray in
    self.sections = sectionsArray
    //reload your table with sectionsArray
})
```

Comment: Now, in the SectionsTableViewController.Swift file on this line: var sections: [Sections] = SectionsData().getSectionsFromData() - I get Missing Argument for parameter #1 in call

Comment: I do apologize, I am very new to programming swift. I do appreciated your help.

Comment: You will need to declare your `sections` somewhere and then call `SectionsData().getSectionsFromData({ data in sections = data })`. This is still an async call so you will need to manage your code to adopt this.

Comment: the sections are defined in  struct in the section.swift file.

Comment: do you think you will be able to edit the file and make available for download? I'm getting very lost with this.

Comment: Sorry, I can't do the project for you. Based on the question you have here, you should search something like `how to asynchronous load uitableview in swift`.

Comment: ok. Well I followed this tutorial: https://www.codebeaulieu.com/34/Creating-a-UITableViewController-with-sections-in-iOS-9 to create what I have now. There is a short video which might help to explain the way my project is coded.